# Why is my Mongoose model returning a blank response even after passing collection name?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern, mongodb-atlas

I have set up a MongoDB cluster called 'nutrition' using Atlas MongoDB and am trying to fetch the documents in that cluster using Mongoose. I am getting a blank list ([]) even after specifying the name of the collection in the Schema definition. I am able to fetch data from that cluster in MongoDB Compass, but not through my backend code. Please help.

The database connection is successful and the router routes to the appropriate controller correctly. I've tried mentioning the name of the cluster while defining the schema in my model like most of the solutions asked to do. I've tried to insert it in new Schema() as well as in mongoose.model()

Here's a document from my cluster called 'nutrition':

```
_id:5c5727667fead009507c0e11
<br>
FoodGroup:"Dairy and Egg Products"
<br>
ShortDescrip:"BUTTER-WITH SALT"<br>
Energy_kcal:"717.0"<br>
Protein_g:"0.85"<br>
Fat_g:"81.11"<br>
Carb_g:"0.06"<br>
Sugar_g:"0.06"<br>
Fiber_g:"0.0"

NutritionModel.js<br>
const mongoose = require('mongoose');<br>
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;<br>
var NutritionSchema = new Schema({<br>
    _id: Object,<br>
    FoodGroup: String,<br>
    ShortDescrip: String,<br>
    Energy_kcal: String,<br>
    Protein_g: String,<br>
    Fat_g: String,<br>
    Carb_g: String,<br>
    Sugar_g: String,<br>
    Fiber_g: String<br>
});<br>
module.exports = mongoose.model('Nutrition', NutritionSchema, 'nutrition');<br>

NutritionController.js<br>
const Nutrition = require('../Models/nutritionModel');<br>
exports.nutritionDetails = function (req, res){<br>
    Nutrition.find({}, function (err, products) {<br>
        if (err) <br>
            res.send(err);<br>
        res.send(products);     //This is always blank!<br>
    });<br>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It might possibly be your _id declaration in your model. You say the type is an object. Try making it an ObjectId instead like this:

```
_id: {
  type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding dbName to the connection string like, I was also facing same problem it, this worked for me:

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    dbName: "Your_db_name"
  }
).then(() => {
  console.log('DB Connected');
},
  (error) => {
    console.log('Error in connecting db', error)
  }
)
```